# Slim, Twig - how to pass var to Twig to base template

Tags: templates, session, twig, slim

I would like to show the number of unreaded msgs in User Panel Box which will appear everytime when user is logged in.

How to pass the number of msg from controler to the user panel box which is included in base layout? 
I can't use routes for that because the panel appears on all pages (index as well).

Now i'm sending it using global session but i think it could be done better. Any clues ?

Controler:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
$unreaded=Model::factory('Message')->filter('getUnreadedGroups',$_SESSION['user_id']);
$_SESSION['unreaded']=$unreaded->opened;}
```

Base layout

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
            <head>
                <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/reset.css" />
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css" />
                <title>{% block page_title %} {% endblock %}</title>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
                <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.scripts.js"></script>
            </head>
            <body>
                <div id="all">

                    <div id="top-container">
                        <div id="logo">test</div>
                        <div id="search-box"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div id="left-side">
                        <div class="menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="nav_dashboard active"><a href="/">Strona główna</a></li>
                                <li class="nav_graphs"><a href="/wszystkie">Wzory</a></li>
                                <li class="nav_forms"><a href="/najnowsze">Najnowsze</a></li>
                                <li class="nav_typography"><a href="/najlepiej-oceniane">Najlepiej oceniane</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="page">
        {% block content %} {% endblock %}
                    </div>

                    <div id="right-side">
                        <div id="login-container">

                            {% if session.user_id is defined %}
                                    {% include 'user_panel.php' %}
                            {% else %}
                                    {% include 'login_form.php' %}
                            {% endif %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </body>
        </html>
```

User Panel Box

```
  <div class="login-top" id="login-form-top">
        <div id="welcome">Witaj, <span>John Doe</span></div>
        <p id="last-login">Ostatnie logowanie:</p>
        <div id="logout-msg-container">
            <div class="logut"><a href="/wyloguj" class="logout">Wyloguj</a></div>
            <a id="msg-number" href="/profil/wiadomosci">
                <span class="number">
                  {% if session.unreaded >0 %}
                    {{ session.unreaded }}
                  {% else %} 0
                  {% endif %}
                </span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <p class="header">Profil użytkownika</p>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/profil/edytuj">Twoje Dane</a></li>
            <li><a href="/profil/galeria">Twoje zbiory</a></li>
            <li><a href="/profil/wiadomosci">Twoje wiadomości</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Typical template

```
{% extends 'layout.php' %}

    {% block page_title %}Najnowsze pliki{% endblock %}
    {% block content %}
                    <div id="page-top">
                        <h1>Najnowsze</h1>
                        <p>+ <span class="blue">12</span> wzorów</p>
                    </div>

                    <div id="main-topvote">
                        <div class="title"><a href="">Najnowsze</a><span>( ostatni tydzień )</span></div>
                        <div class="content">
                            {% for file in files %}
                                <p>{{ file.idFile }}<br/> {{ file.date_add }}<br/> {{ file.desc }}<br/> {{ file.title }}<br/><br/></p>
                            {% else %}  
                                <p>There are currently no articles.</p>
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
    {% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

I havent tested this ( https://github.com/fabpot/Twig/issues/293 ):

Base layout:

```
...
<div id="right-side">
    {% block side %}
        {% block side-login %}
            {% if session.user_id is defined %}
               {% include 'user_panel.php' %}
            {% else %}
               {% include 'login_form.php' %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
    {% endblock %}
</div>
...
```

Typical template:

```
...
{% block side %}
    {% set count = 12 %}
    {% block side-login %}
        {{ parent() }}
    {% endblock %}
{% endblock %}
...
```

So you can use {{count}} in your User Panel Box.
You can also try to skip the side-login block definition .. but i am not sure.